新規ChromeOSデバイスを一括でMDM登録する際のアセットIDの一括登録方法について
MDM登録した新規の各ChromeOSデバイスに一括でアセットIDを登録したいと考えております。
その際、APIを使う方法があるのではないかと考えております。
もし、その認識があっていましたら、具体的なアセットIDの一括登録手順をご教示いただけますでしょうか。
認識が違った場合、どのような手順があるのかご教示いただきたいです。
ChromeOSデバイスは数千台等とても多くの数を想定しており、手動で各デバイスに設定する方法は避けたいと考えております。
